# Getting everything from an xpub

Tags: python, xpub

I wrote a small Web Application to display data to the user. I want a crawler in the background, fetching all the data (transaction etc) on all addresses. All the user enters is his xpub. I know this is possible but I am a newbie in bitcoin development. So I have zero clue how to achieve this.
The crawler will be written in Python, so if you know a good library to start with, I would be happy to play around.

Comment: This question-and-answer website wasn't designed for making software library recommendations so it isn't especially suited to that purpose.

Comment: locally generate addresses from the xpub (i hope this is what you mean!) and then just make a request against your bitcoin core instance with txindex enabled (this is gross for user privacy, but so is your entire idea anyway)